# Understanding how $ZF$ proves finite choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

The finite axiom of choice is a theorem of $ZF$ and states that any finite family of non empty sets has a choice function. The standard answer on why $ZF$ proves finite choice is that I can use existential instantiation a finite number of times. But this is a finite number of times in the meta theory and would make sense if all models of $ZF$ only had standard natural numbers. I cannot use instantiation some nonstandard number of times in the meta theory. Also by overspill I cannot state choice for simply standard numbers

So I'm wondering how $ZF$ really proves that finite choice holds. My first guess is to just use induction. An empty family of sets has the empty set as a choice function so it is obvious. Assume that for a family of $n$ sets I have choice then given $X=\{X_i\}_{i\in n+1}$ of non empty sets (I use instantiation to fix a bijection from $F$ to $n+1$ then there is a choice function $f_n$ for $\{X_i\}_{i\in n}$ and I extend it to a choice function to $\{X_i\}_{i\in n+1}$ by choosing one element from $X_{n+1}$. I believe this would be the correct proof minus some details.

Comment: Yes the proof is by induction on the number of sets in the given finite family. And so, when applied in a model of ZF, it covers all families that are finite in the sense of the model, even if they are infinite in the metatheory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like thinking about individual models in this context; even though that's not necessary, and ultimately requires an appeal to the completeness theorem which is not needed if one just reasons directly in $\mathsf{ZF}$, I find it satisfying to play with the models directly. (I think for me the point is that I a priori care *more* about what's true of all models of a theory $T$ than what is deducible from $T$ via a fixed inference system, and so the model-theoretic line leaps out as more natural to me.)

Fix a model $M\models\mathsf{ZF}$. Within $M$, we can define the set $U$ of finite ordinals $n$ such that choice fails for some $X$ with $\vert X\vert=n$. We want to show $U=\emptyset$. Of course $U$ has no *standard* elements, but that's not helpful here.

The point is that $\mathsf{ZF}$ is strong enough to prove that every nonempty set of ordinals - let alone of *finite* ordinals - has a least element. So assuming for conteradiction that $U\not=\emptyset$, let $u=\min(U)$. Let $X$ be a set of nonempty sets such that $\vert X\vert=u$ but $X$ has no choice function. Let $y\in X$, let $a\in y$, and let $X'=X\setminus\{y\}$.

By definition of $u$, we have in $M$ a choice function $f$ for $X'$. Now in $M$ we also have the set $$g:=f\cup\{\langle y, a\rangle\}.$$ But this $g$ is clearly a choice function for $X$, so we have a contradiction. This tells us that $M\models$ "Every finite set of nonempty sets has a choice function." Since $M$ was an arbitrary model of $\mathsf{ZF}$, by the completeness theorem we get $\mathsf{ZF}\models$ "Every finite set of nonempty sets has a choice function" as desired.

Note as a reality check that we **did** crucially use finiteness in the above argument (so we don't get a $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof of full $\mathsf{AC}$); do you see where?

> The only way we knew that $X'$ had a choice function was the implicit fact that $\vert X'\vert<u$ since $X'\subsetneq X$.

Comment: I know nothing of models and the like but this has caught my interest. Should I remove all references to $M$ from your post, it seems to me I still have a sensible proof of the claim. Where does your proof need to refer to a specified model? Is it that $U$ cannot be defined without the context of a model??

Comment: @FShrike Nope, the entire argument can be "de-modelized" resulting in a deduction inside $\mathsf{ZF}$. I've edited the preamble to be clearer on this point.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying